# missing unique(%) values and broken bar charts in pandas profile report

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, pandas-profiling

I am using Python 2.7 and Pandas Profiling to generate a report out of a dataframe. Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_profiling

# the actual dataset is very large, just providing the two elements of the list 
data = [{'polarity': 0.0, 'name': u'danesh bhopi', 'sentiment': 'Neutral', 'tweet_id': 1049952424818020353, 'original_tweet_id': 1049952424818020353, 'created_at': Timestamp('2018-10-10 14:18:59'), 'tweet_text': u"Wouldn't mind aus 120 all-out but before that would like to see a Finch \U0001f4af #PakVAus #AUSvPAK", 'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', 'location': u'pune', 'retweet_count': 0, 'geo': '', 'favorite_count': 0, 'screen_name': u'DaneshBhope'}, {'polarity': 1.0, 'name': u'kamal Kishor parihar', 'sentiment': 'Positive', 'tweet_id': 1049952403980775425, 'original_tweet_id': 1049952403980775425, 'created_at': Timestamp('2018-10-10 14:18:54'), 'tweet_text': u'@the_summer_game What you and Australia think\nPlay for\n win \nDraw\n or....! #PakvAus', 'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>', 'location': u'chembur Mumbai ', 'retweet_count': 0, 'geo': '', 'favorite_count': 0, 'screen_name': u'kaluparihar1'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data) #data is a python list containing python dictionaries
pfr = pandas_profiling.ProfileReport(df)
pfr.to_file("df_report.html")
```

The screenshot of the part of the df_report.html file is below:[image]

As you can see in the image, the Unique(%) field in all the variables is 0.0 although the columns have unique values.

Apart from this, the chart in the 'location' variable is broken. There is no bar for the values 22, 15, 4 and the only bar is for the maximum value only. This is happening in all the variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should [edit] a [mcve] of your current code into your post so we can see what you've already done and where it might be going wrong.

Comment: @asongtoruin I have edited it, please check now. thanks

Comment: This example isn't "Complete" - please include an example of what `data` is. Again, remember we're looking for something "Minimal" - you don't need to include the entire dataframe, just a sample or dummy data that would replicate your problem

Comment: @asongtoruin edited again. kindly recheck